# asp.net App_LocalResources folder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I would like to have App_LocalResources folder outside web application folder, so that I could deploy updated resx files and web app. independent of each other.

Reasons: We do not want to change current deploy tool.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way the default resource manager works in asp.net is it picks the resex entries for the respective aspx file from the App_LocalResources folder in the current directory. As far as I know this behavior is not something you can configure (i.e to ask it to pick entries from a different folder!) But there is a workaround, that you could implement your own Resource Manager and let it picks entries from a location you specify it to. Found [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t108992-custom-resource-manager-in-asp-net-2-0-a.html) and [this](http://asp-net-whidbey.blogspot.com/2006/03/aspnet-20-custom-resource-provider.html) while googling. Hope that helps.